# Type hint self class type in method

Tags: python

En primer lugar, agradezco mucho vuestra ayuda.

Estoy intentando forzar el tipado de variables pero, cuando fuerzo el tipo del argumento de entrada *reference_point* a *ECEFPoint* en el método **los_distance** obtengo el error **Unresolved reference 'ECEFPoint'**

```
class ECEFPoint:
    def __init__(self, point_id: int, x: float, y: float, z: float):
        self.point_id: int = point_id
        self.x: float = x
        self.y: float = y
        self.z: float = z

    def los_distance(self, reference_point: ECEFPoint) -> [[float, float, float], float]:
        x_dif = reference_point.x - self.x
        y_dif = reference_point.y - self.y
        z_dif = reference_point.z - self.z
        dif = [x_dif, y_dif, z_dif]
        return [dif, norm(dif)]
```

Imagino que la clase *ECEFPoint* todavía no está definida pero no se cómo solucionarlo sin eliminar el tipado. Muchas gracias

Comment: Hola! Este es Stack Overflow en Español. Por favor, traduce tu pregunta.

Comment: Lo siento, me ha dirigido aquí directamente, mi intención era publicarlo en la parte en inglés; perdón

Comment: y si lo haces en dos clases distintas?

Comment: No entiendo tu propuesta. El argumento de entrada debe ser un objeto ECEFPoint. Lo que podría hacer es sacar el método de la clase como una función y que en su lugar obtuviera dos objetos ECEFPoint pero no es lo que busco porque tengo ese método para otros sistemas de referencia (otras clases de puntos pero con otra nomenclatura) también y el problema se me repite

Comment: No puedes definir un método que involucre su propia clase, todavía no existe una instancia de ese *nuevo tipo.*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ya está solucionado.

Si se trata de **Python 3.7+:**

```
from __future__ import annotations
```

Fuente: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33533148/how-do-i-specify-that-the-return-type-of-a-method-is-the-same-as-the-class-itsel

**Explicación detallada y fuentes**

El error se basa en que, la clase no está definida, entonces no se puede usar dentro de la propia definición de clase para forzar el tipado de una variable.

Python 3.7 introduce PEP 563 que evalúa las anotaciones posteriormente y así se evita el error. La línea que soluciona el error lo que hace es almacenar las anotaciones como strings de manera automática, evitando así el error. En versiones anteriores a Python 3.7 se deben poner los nombres de las clases en formato string, es decir quedaría:

**Python 3.7+ (PEP0563 https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0563/):**

```
from __future__ import annotations

class ECEFPoint:
    def __init__(self, point_id: int, x: float, y: float, z: float):
        self.point_id: int = point_id
        self.x: float = x
        self.y: float = y
        self.z: float = z

    def los_distance(self, reference_point: ECEFPoint) -> [[float, float, float], float]:
        x_dif = reference_point.x - self.x
        y_dif = reference_point.y - self.y
        z_dif = reference_point.z - self.z
        dif = [x_dif, y_dif, z_dif]
        return [dif, norm(dif)]
```

**Python <3.7 (PEP0484 https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0484/#forward-references):**

```
class ECEFPoint:
    def __init__(self, point_id: int, x: float, y: float, z: float):
        self.point_id: int = point_id
        self.x: float = x
        self.y: float = y
        self.z: float = z

    def los_distance(self, reference_point: 'ECEFPoint') -> [[float, float, float], float]:
        x_dif = reference_point.x - self.x
        y_dif = reference_point.y - self.y
        z_dif = reference_point.z - self.z
        dif = [x_dif, y_dif, z_dif]
        return [dif, norm(dif)]
```

Comment: Amplia tu respuesta y explica el error y su corrección.

Comment: Gracias por el apunte, he ido demasiado al grano. Saludos

Comment: Enhorabuena, después de editarla ha sido una gran respuesta final. :)